# Update libraries after manual change

Tags: ruby

So I started working on my first open-source contribution in ruby. There I have the library I'm working on in the `/lib/` folder. Now when I tried changing the code, my program (which uses the library) still uses the old code.

For example: Broke a function on purpose by deleting its end keyword (which should be causing an immediate crash), but it kept working perfectly after I did.

Another example was changing the code in such a way it should still work (mutating the output string) but it still returned the old string.
[image: Image of the code that I broke on purpose]

```bash
user~$ bin/ruby-hyphen -V "this is a test sentence"
this is a test sen-tence
```

Does anyone know if I have to tell the runtime to refresh it or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why that happened. The file has a `*.gemspec`, which made it act as if it was a gem. To see the changes I needed to enter:

```bash
gem build *.gemspec
bundle exec rake install
```

Or, if you want to develop quicker: change everywhere you `require` it into a `require_relative`. That should also fix it. I hope this question helps someone in the future!